# Angular ui-grid expandable row not displaying like parent

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I have modified the styles to change the color of the grid rows as well as text. This works fine when the grid is used by itself, but when using expandable rows, the expanded rows do not inherit the properties defined on the main grid. Instead, it is trying to use the original styles that come out of the box. Does anyone know how to make the expanded rows use the same css as the main grid?

Comment: sorry everyone. I was blind and missed the css controlling this.

Comment: .expandableRow .ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) .ui-grid-cell {
 background-color: #fff;
}

.expandableRow .ui-grid-row:nth-child(even) .ui-grid-cell {
 background-color: #000
}